# Combining 2 Functions to fire at pageinit

Tags: jquery

I have two functions I want to fire at pageinit, one after the other; first to fire an ajax call, then to bind a click function to `<a>` elements, however my attempts have failed.

The two functions are as follows:

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", "#featuredtracks", function( e ) {
var surl =  "http://localhost/musicapp/includes/alltracks.php";
var id = 1;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: surl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "featuredtrackscallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function(response) {
    }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {           
       alert('Unknown error ' + status);
    }       
 });        
});
```

and

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", "#featuredtracks", function( e ) {
    $(this).find('a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        passDataObject.selectedHref = this.href;
    });
});
```

If I can get the correct way to combine them I would be grateful. Lastly if I can get a tutorial to transform this ajax request to a jQuery ajax request would be great.

Comment: `passDataObject` should be response from ajax?

Comment: 1) From comments it seems there are many requirements not laid out in the question.  2) It is not clear exactly what the asker is trying to accomplish.  One can imply the question, and the solutions provided do indeed "combine" the functions, but somehow not in the way the asker desires.  Those extra desires are not clarified anywhere and thus there is no way we can provide a solution. 3) Without a clearly laid out problem(you say it "doesn't work", we need details) and desired solution/requirements. We could guess 100 things and not give you the answer you want.  Sorry, voting to close.

Comment: Voting to closed based on what? I gave all the information the combination is not working and showing no errors. Since it is not working am looking for a better way to implement what the combination of functions was to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
  $(document).on( "pageinit", "#featuredtracks", function( e ) {
    var surl =  "http://localhost/musicapp/includes/alltracks.php";
    var id = 1;
        $.ajax({
        //rest of code
        }).done(function(data){
            $(this).find('a').unbind('click').click(function() {
               passDataObject.selectedHref = this.href;
            });
        }).fail(function(){
            //when something fail
        })
    });
```

Also from jQuery documentation:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

---

So use **done** instead of `success` and **fail** instead `error`

Comment: this actually still doesn't work. If I put an alert before the unbind function it fires. however if I put one inside the unbind it never fires and as such the values are never copied

Comment: Question: Can you explain me, what you want to do after receive data from ajax? I'm little confused actually.

Comment: After i get my JSON from the server and the page is ready I want to execute a function everytime an `<a>` is clicked. what the function does is get the value from the address bar which is stored like this `?id=3`

Comment: I am wondering if I should do the unbind a later point in the page creation what page event happens after a paginit?

Comment: Why you want unbind when you try execute some code after clicking?

Comment: Try this in done: `$(this).find('a').on('click', function() {
               passDataObject.selectedHref = this.href;
            });`

Comment: This doesn't work either can you point me to a better way to have history when using ajax pages with jqm then seeing that this solution doesn't seem to work. History and bookmarking if possible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25634/discussion-between-woocash-and-kern-elliott)

Answer (score 0):

This will bind after the ajax request is made, but not neccesarily after the response to the request.  I.e. because the ajax request is asynchronous.

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", "#featuredtracks", function( e ) {
var surl =  "http://localhost/musicapp/includes/alltracks.php";
var id = 1;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: surl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "featuredtrackscallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function(response) {
    }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {           
       alert('Unknown error ' + status);
    }       
 });//end ,ajax

 $(this).find('a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        passDataObject.selectedHref = this.href;
    });

});//end pageinit
```

This will bind to anchors after the request succeeds, so do this if you want to wait until the server responds to your ajax request:

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", "#featuredtracks", function( e ) {
var surl =  "http://localhost/musicapp/includes/alltracks.php";
var id = 1;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: surl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "featuredtrackscallback",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function(response) {
         alert('test fire when ajax response succeeds');
         //put a break point here with your browser, then run  $(this).find('a') in console to see if it finds the element
         $(this).find('a').unbind('click'); 
         $(this).find('a').click(function() {
          alert('test fire when clicked');
          passDataObject.selectedHref = this.href;              
      });
    }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {           
       alert('Unknown error ' + status);
    }       
 });//end ,ajax
});//end pageinit
```

However I have no idea where the variable passDataObject comes from so not sure if you are intending that to be part of the response or not.

Comment: the passDataObject is a global variable however if I try to alert the value within the unbind function it still doesn't fire

Comment: @kern I added a comment and some code changes.  If it's not firing then put a breakpoint at the comment, so that you are in the scope of the success handler.  When it pauses on the breakpoint, then in the console  run `$(this).find('a')` and see it finds the element.  It may be failing to find the element.  Also watch for javascript errors in the console because the stack trace will show you what line the problem is on.

Comment: This doesn't work either can you point me to a better way to have history when using ajax pages with jqm then seeing that this solution doesn't seem to work. History and bookmarking if possible

Comment: @Kern When you say it doesn't work, you mean the alerts aren't showing up, or you are getting javascript errors, did you try to debug it.  Also you didn't say anything about history/bookmarking in the question you posted or any of your previous comments anywhere on this page, this is the first time you've mentioned that goal.  So I honestly don't know what you are talking about or what you are trying accomplish.

Comment: I debugged it am not getting an errors at all and no alerts are firing the function itself is being skipped for some reason. This function was to help me do history/bookmarking for my web app in jqm but as it is not working am looking for a new solution